# Lower bound on Shannon capacity of a Cayley graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics, extremal-graph-theory

I was reading up on the Shannon capacity of graphs and came across [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.05685) on the Shannon capacity of Cayley graphs. Though the article deals primarily with the linear Shannon capacity, defined differently from the regular Shannon capacity, it makes the statement that $\Theta(G) \geq \sqrt{n}$ where $\Theta(G)$ denotes the regular Shannon capacity and $G$ is a Cayley graph.

How can one prove that the Shannon capacity of a Cayley graph is lower bounded by $\sqrt{n}$?

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is of course not lower bounded by $\sqrt{n}$: the complete graph $K_n$ is a Cayley graph (every nonzero generator of $\mathbb{F}_n$), and it has a max independent set of size 1, so its Shannon capacity is just 1.

That paper is largely discussing *self-complementary* Cayley graphs, those where G is isomorphic to its own complement. In that case they show that a linear code achieves a capacity of at least $\sqrt{n}$, so the Shannon capacity is definitely at least $\sqrt{n}$.